# How to handle sending multiple messages over a socket connection?

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, printwriter

I'm a bit of a beginner programmer so it's possible this is quite obvious and I'm overlooking the answer. But on to the question.

I have a two-part program (its a little more complicated than this example, but the situation is the same). The program has multiple messages fired between the client and the server. I have a PrintWriter on the server-side to send messages to the client, and on the client, I have a BufferedReader to read the messages sent.
When this example is run, I'm given two lines as output. The first message is both messages, and the second is NULL. What I am wondering is if there is a way to basically halt the server until I am ready for the second message, so that I can do something on the client-side before the second message is sent.

I am hoping to not use `Thread.Sleep`, as I would rather the Server wait around until the Client says it is ready.

This is the client:

```
    public class Client{
     public void run(){
        Socket socket = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try{
            socket = new socket("LocalHost",1234); 
            in = socket.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));          
        } 

        String messageFromServer = "";
        try{
            messageFromServer=reader.readLine();
        }

        System.out.println(messageFromServer);

        String messageFromServer = "";

        try{
            messageFromServer=reader.readLine();
        } 
         System.out.println(messagefromServer);

        //close everything
    }
  }
```

This is the server:

```
    public class Server{
        public void run(){
           ServerSocket server = null;
           Socket client = null;
           try{
               server = new ServerSocket(1234);
               client = server.accept();
           }

            PrintWriter writer = null;
            OutputStream out = null;

            try{
                 out = client.getOutputStream();
                 writer = new PrintWriter(out, true);
            }

            writer.write("Hi I'm a server");

            //do some stuff that takes some time, user input, etc. etc.

            writer.write("I'm still a server");

            //close everything
        }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Your client can send an ACK message, and the server thread will wait for it before sending another message.

Comment: You could use a pooling mechanism, allowing the client to poll the server

Comment: So you want to make your server `"SLEEP"` without using `Thread.Sleep`?

Comment: I strongly recommend you stop and carefully read the [Java Socket Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)

Comment: This code does not compile. You don't need sleeps in blocking networking code. If you got `null` from `readLine()`, the peer has cloed the connection. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the way you currently have you code is the fact that you are using a `BufferedReader`, but the server is not terminating it's messages with a new line.

When you close the `writer`, the client is reaching the EOF or EOS and unblocking the read so it appears that both strings are being sent at once...

If you do something like...

```
writer.write("Hi I'm a server\n");
// This will force the message to be written to the client and picked up ;)
writer.flush();
writer.write("I'm still a server\n");
writer.flush();
```

Then you will get the messages seperatly...

Comment: Perfect, I figured it was something obvious that I was overlooking.
Is there a way to write a Newline character without having the Reader stop reading?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) to read Objects instead of Strings.
This way you will read only one Message(String in your case) every call to ObjectInputStream.readObject();

BTW you can read the first message, "do something" and then read the second message. you don't have to read all of the sent messages at once.
If there are no other messages, then your thread will be blocked when trying to read an object from the ObjectInputStream.
Use it like:
 `ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(  socket.getInputStream() )`

Comment: Nice advice, how does that help?

Comment: There, much better ;)